# Evaluate $P[X^2> Y^2]$

Tags: integration, probability-distributions

> Let $X$ and $Y$ have the joint probability density function 
>   $$f(x,y)= \begin{cases}cxye^{-(x^2+2y^2)}, & x>0,y>0 \\ 0, &\text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$ 
>   Evaluate $c$ and $P[X^2> Y^2]$.

Trial: We know that

\begin{align} 
c\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}xye^{-(x^2+2y^2)}\,dx\,dy&=1\\ \implies c(\int_{0}^{\infty}xe^{-x^2}\,dx)(\int_{0}^{\infty}ye^{-2y^2})\,dy&=1 \\ \implies c &=8
\end{align}

Now $$P[X^2>Y^2]= \iint_{x^2>y^2} 8xye^{-(x^2+2y^2)}\,dx\,dy$$
 Then I try to solve it by polar transformation. But I can not find limits of $r$ and $\theta$.Mainly I want to evaluate $P[X^2>Y^2]$. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The transformation you want is $x=r \cos{\theta}$, $y= \frac{r}{\sqrt{2}} \sin{\theta}$, and $dx \, dy = \frac{r}{\sqrt{2}} dr \, d \theta$.  As far as the integration limits go, $x^2 > y^2$ implies $0 < \tan{\theta} < \sqrt{2}$, while  $r \in [0,\infty)$.

The integral then becomes

$$\frac{8}{2} \underbrace{\int_0^{\infty} dr \: r^3 e^{-r^2}}_{1/2} \underbrace{\int_0^{\arctan{\sqrt{2}}} d \theta \: \sin{\theta} \cos{\theta}}_{(1/2) \sin^2{\arctan{\sqrt{2}}}=(1/2)(2/3) = 1/3} = \frac{2}{3} $$

Answer (score 0):

$$P[X^2>Y^2]= \iint_{x^2>y^2} 8xye^{-(x^2+2y^2)}\,dx\,dy$$
$$P[X^2>Y^2]= \int_{y=0}^{y=1} \int_{x=-y}^{x=\infty} 8xye^{-(x^2+2y^2)}\,dx\,dy + \int_{y=1}^{y=\infty} \int_{x=y}^{x=\infty} 8xye^{-(x^2+2y^2)}\,dx\,dy$$
$$=\dfrac{2}{3}$$
I could be wrong I did it in a haste.

Comment: Please explain the breaking of limits.

Comment: @Argha, you can draw the figure of the $x^2>y^2$ and see how the integral behaves. I am merely conserving area.